# How get file path from plugin wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

hi i want use `wp_enqueue_style` function to register `style.css` file from plugin wordpress folder not in directory folder

for example when i want register `style.css` from theme directory i use this code below

```
wp_enqueue_style ('bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

the above code it is register the `bootstrap.min.css` file from this below directory

```
/wamp/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-themefolder/css/bootstrab.min.css
```

but how i can register the same file when the file within the plugin folder us below

```
/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

i must use any function instead of `get_template_directory_uri()` for get plugin folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `plugins_url()`

To get the absolute URL to the plugins directory use [`plugins_url( $path, $plugin )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url).

```
plugins_url() 
// http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins

plugins_url( '', __FILE__ )  
// http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin

plugins_url( '/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__ )  
// http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This function retrieves the URL without the trailing slash.

### `plugin_dir_url()`

To get the absolute URL to the directory of the file use the [`plugin_dir_url( $file )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url).

```
plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  
// http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin/

plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . css/bootstrap.min.css
// http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This function retrieves the URL with the trailing slash.

### `trailingslashit()`


To ensure that the path ends with a trailing slash use [`trailingslashit( $string )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit).